# Nested React Router V6 Wildcard issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Backstory**: Looking to setup nested routes that match on a wildcard for my **/items**, **/item**, **/service**, **/services** routes.

**Issue**: Routes are not matching correctly when using wildcard on `react-router-dom` V6.

**Console Warnings:**

> You rendered descendant `<Routes>` (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/"
> (under `<Route path="/">`) but the parent route path has no trailing
> "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore
> and therefore the child routes will never render.
>
> Please change the parent `<Route path="/"> to <Route path="*">`.

**Code example:**

ParentNavigation.jsx

```
const ParentNavigation: React.FC<> = (props) => {

    const defaultRoutes = [
        { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
        { path: '/', element: <Home />, index: true },
        { path: '/product/:id/*', element: <ProductPage /> },
        { path: '/products/*', element: <ProductsPage /> },
        { path: '/item/:id/*', element: <ItemPage /> },
        { path: '/items/*', element: <ItemsPage /> },
        { path: '/service/:id/*', element: <ServicePage /> },
        { path: '/services/*', element: <ServicesPage /> },
        { path: '/404', element: <ErrorPage /> }
    ];

    const mainRoutes = {
        path: '/',
        element: <App />,
        children: [...defaultRoutes, ...routes]
    };

    const routing = useRoutes([mainRoutes]);

    return routing;
};
```

NestedComponent.jsx

```
const SidePanelRouter = (props) => {
    let location = useLocation();
    const isOpen = location.pathname.includes('/recommendations');
    return isOpen && <SidePanel>
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/*/recommendations" element={<Recommendations />} />
                <Route path="/*/recommendations/edit" element={<RecommendationEdit />} />
                <Route path="/*/recommendations/list" element={<RecommendationList />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    </SidePanel>;
};
```

Comment: The `"*"` wildcard matcher is only valid at the end of a path. Where is `SidePanelRouter` being rendered? Can you share a more complete [mcve]? Based on the error I'm guessing that `Home` is trying to render some descendent routes but because its path is `"/"` it can't and throws the invariant error.